# Multiple-choice picture quiz for young students

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to make a quiz with multiple submit buttons.  I want a picture to appear with ten buttons.  Each time the test-taker presses a button I want the value to be posted and the picture to change.  So far I've tried three approaches:-

1.Using onclick and javascript I could get all the animation done but the values didn't get posted.  From Google I get the impression I'd have to use more javascript to submit the values?

2.Using variables in php the first picture would show and first value would post but then nothing happened, adding a loop meant that all the pictures appeared on top of the other without waiting for any buttons to be clicked...

3.I tried doing separate html pages for each picture, the value then gets posted to a php file, which does $score++; and goes to the next html file, but then the $score isn't right.  Because it's a local variable?  Would this mean I'd have to hold the value in MySQL to get at it?  Also this seems a very wasteful way to program the whole thing...

Here is the code for no. 2:

```
<?php
include 'header.php';

if ($round==1) {$ans='Banana';}
if ($round==2) {$ans='Book';}
if ($round==3) {$ans='Pencil';}
...and so on

if ($_POST['submit']==$ans) {$score++; echo "Right!"; $round++; }
else
{$round++;}
?>

<html>
<form action="index.php" method="post">

<input type="submit" class="button1"  name="submit" value="Banana">
<input type="submit" class="button2" name="submit" value="Balloon">
<input type="submit" class="button3" name="submit" value="Dog">
<input type="submit" class="button4" name="submit" value="Mouse">
<input type="submit" class="button5" name="submit" value="Chair">
<input type="submit" class="button6" name="submit" value="Twelve">
<input type="submit" class="button7" name="submit" value="Pen">
<input type="submit" class="button8" name="submit" value="Book">
<input type="submit" class="button9" name="submit" value="Ball">
<input type="submit" class="button10" name="submit" value="Elephant">
</form>
</html>

<?php

if($ans=="Banana")
{   
echo '<img src="Banana.png" id="picture" class="picture" height="600" width="600" alt="script.aculo.us" />';
}
if($ans=="Pencil")
{   
echo '<img src="Pencil.png" id="picture" class="picture" height="600" width="600" alt="script.aculo.us" />';
}
{   
echo '<img src="Book.png" id="picture" class="picture" height="500" width="500" alt="script.aculo.us" />';
}
...and so on

include 'footer.php';

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you show first option code?

Comment: Have you tried using `a` tags instead of input buttons?

Answer (score 0):

The elegant solution in your case is using javascript (with onClick) and AJAX (a library that enables AJAX queries like jQuery - http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).Every time a user click selects a button, you should update the score value in javascript and request the url for the new image and the correct answer for it. You should send the final score when the user clicks on the last button send it. 
 More details on AJAX you can find here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp
 Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Among the approaches, the third one is better than others. Generally on MCQ pages, the question are kept or separate pages. The problem with your local variable can you solved if you use ***sessions***

```
$_SESSSION['score'] += $score
echo $_SESSION['score'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have each button submit its value to a function (onclick="answered('pencil')")

I'd then have an array of the order of the right answers, and a counter integer for what round the user is on. In the answered function I would compare the submitted value to the item in the answer array at position 'round' (maybe minus one depending on how you want to count) and maybe increment the guess count (if that's what you're scoring)

When the two values match, increment the counter, and change the src attribute of the image. If not, display some "guess again" message

When the final round is complete, you can post the guess count to your server for storing (if that was your intent)

here is some sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="buttons">
<button onclick="answered('banana')">Banana</button>
<button onclick="answered('balloon')">Balloon</button>
<button onclick="answered('dog')">Dog</button>
<button onclick="answered('mouse')">Mouse</button>
<button onclick="answered('chair')">Chair</button>
<button onclick="answered('twelve')">Twelve</button>
<button onclick="answered('pen')">Pen</button>
<button onclick="answered('book')">Book</button>
<button onclick="answered('ball')">Ball</button>
<button onclick="answered('elephant')">Elephant</button>
</div>
<div id="msg"></div>
<img id="photo" />

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var turn=0;
var guess=0;
//this is the order of correct answers
var answers = ['banana','book','elephant','dog','pen','balloon','mouse','ball','chair','twelve'];
//these are the image urls (yours would be more like 'Pen.png'
var images= ['http://caloriesinbanana.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Calories-in-Banana.jpeg','http://www.instructables.com/image/FZJO197FB11U3O8/Write-a-good-book.jpg','http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/004/cache/african-elephant_435_600x450.jpg','http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-pKym47-kmsk/Trj8aES5iRI/AAAAAAAADII/5tUPH7YZUnw/s1600/Dog.jpg','http://tacticalpens.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/surefire-tactical-pen.jpg','http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-zLp3E7kSKm4/TV6W5FNY44I/AAAAAAAAAy8/lvievPXdh68/s1600/red+balloon.jpg','http://kids.mdbc.gov.au/__data/page/735/Pilliga_Mouse.JPG','http://thelatesthiss.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/soccer-ball1.png','http://remodelista.com/img/sub/uimg//02-2011/ikea-olle-chair-red.jpg','http://ctmls.ctreal.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/twelvekillerblogposts.jpg'];

document.getElementById('photo').setAttribute('src',images[turn]);
function answered(a){
    guess++;
    if(a==answers[turn]){
        turn++;
        if(turn!=answers.length){
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='<span style="color:#FFF;background-color:#0F0;">Great Job!!</span>';
            setTimeout(clr,1000);
            document.getElementById('photo').setAttribute('src',images[turn]);
        }
        else{
            alert('You finished the quiz. You were right '+answers.length+'/'+guess+' times for a score of '+Math.round(100*answers.length/guess)+'%');
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='<span style="color:#FFF;background-color:#F00;">Guess Again</span>';
        setTimeout(clr,2000);
    }
}

function clr(){
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='';
}

</script>
</html>
```